# Chnging the value of columns from postive to negative

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, absolute-value

```
ID   Y     Z     W
1    aa   AA    -6.8
2    bb    FF      5.8
3     cc    DD     -9.25
.      .     .      .
.       .    .       .
.        .    .       .
```

i want to changes the above data frame replacing the negative value by postive values in such case the value of column Y and Z are also changed.
The new data frame looks like

```
ID   Y     Z     W
1    aa   aa    6.8
2    bb    FF      5.8
3     cc    cc    9.25
.      .     .      .
.       .    .       .
.        .    .       .
```

Any one can help me with the r code ?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far and why didn’t it work? What is the rule for changing both the case and value of `Z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get the job done.

```
library("dplyr")

Y <- c("aa","bb","cc")
Z <- c("aa", "FF", "cc")
W <- c(-6.8,5.8,-9.25)

Test_Data <- data.frame(Y,Z,W) 

New_Data <- Test_Data %>%
  mutate(
    Z = if_else(W<0,Y,Z),
    W = abs(W)
    )
```